# Is it possible to make React component to WASM(Web Assembly)?

Tags: reactjs, webassembly

I am trying to make a universal component that can be used through out all other frameworks like Angular or Vue.

In short, I am trying to use a React component in Angular without using module federation. (Or even in Vue if possible)

Is there an way to convert React component into a wasm pkg?

Comment: That is Wasm -> react. I am wondering if I can react -> wasm